# Is it okay to touch type with several different finger placements?

Tags: technique, typing

I typed using a QWERTY keyboard for years since my childhood, but I never learned how to type properly and I just type the way I type instead. I use all of my fingers (I had the feelings of that), but I can't describe which fingers press which keyboard button.

Until recently, I just knew that I have been doing it wrong. Then, I tried to learn touch typing instead of the messed up typing skill that I got, and it was better. I went from 50-70 WPM to 60-80 WPM in just a day learning it.

But even though I learned to touch type properly, I still couldn't move away from some of my 'finger misplacements' to optimize my typing skills. The mistakes that I still made were:

- Pressing ZXCV using left thumb
- Pressing space using right point finger
- Pressing U with right middle finger (and maybe other fingers beside U)
- Not using right shift when capitalizing left keystrokes
- And (maybe) many more that I didn't recognize

I tried to change my habits, but it's already stuck in my brain. I keep forgetting which finger should press which keystroke and so on. I wanted to raise my WPM by touch typing, but I'm just comfortable with the way I type, even though I don't know if that is a good thing or not.

Will keeping those habits make me type slower? If it does, then what should I do?

By the way, I know that 60-80 WPM is good enough for me for literature, but I'd prefer to upgrade it just for fun and to improve my typing accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will make you slower, but I know that I don't follow what they tried to teach me in middle school and I'm fine. I type my own way really, I don't really line up my fingers on the f and h keys and then just move them a bit, I rest my wrists on the edge of the laptop and go from there.

One thing that might slow you down though, is changing computers. Different ones might have different sized keyboards which can throw off your muscle memory, and if its just a keyboard then you have to kinda hold your hands off the table a tad. Still, you should be fine. I wouldn't worry too much about it since you'll probably be thinking about what to write next more than actually writing it.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient ways to type require a different keyboard layout. On the current keyboards in many languages, some fingers are used more than others, which slows you down. Alternative keyboard layouts are available on the internet, but they all require that you completely relearn writing and they limit you to a computer on which that layout is installed. If you don't want to invest a few weeks to learn a new layout and a few months to become fluent and need to work at computers you don't own, these alternative keyboard layouts aren't feasible for you.

Whether you use a more efficient or the standard keyboard layout in your language, to type efficiently as a writer **you must be able to type without looking at the keyboard**.

The basic idea behind the standard ten finger typing system is that you place your hands and use your fingers in a way that you don't have to look at the keyboard because you know where each key is from the positioning of your hands. That is very useful, because it not only allows you to type faster, but it also allows you to look at what you write or your notes or a text you copy. This helps your focus and allows you to better think and be creative while you type.

So whatever your method is, first make sure your method allows you to blind type (also called touch type). If you can't, you need to change your typing method.

As for speeding up your method, I don't *know* whether your method is slower than the correct standard typing method – we would have to conduct an experiment in which we compae a group of standard typists with a group of typists that have learned and used your method equally long –, but it *seems* to me that at least some of your finger movements must be less efficent, slower, and maybe require you to look at the keyboard. Only you can say if you feel that you do movements that are slower than others. If so, I would correct my practice.

To do that, you need to really relearn to type properly. That is, you need to correctly ingrain the key-finger assignment by the rhythmic repetitive exercises used in most typing courses. Relearning is more difficult than learning, because you have to go against what you know and are used to, and you can only achieve that through sustained, persistent effort.

For me that effort would be worthwhile, but you'll have to decide for yourself if you want to invest the necessary time.